# Application Insights Pageviews have different operation_Ids to requests

Tags: .net-core, azure-application-insights

We have a .Net Core application (it's a little out of date - netcoreapp2.2) which is successfully logging all requests, traces, events to Application Insights. I can even see operation_parentId successfully linking requests down to dependencies and then to requests in the API server.

In startup.cs there is:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

Additionally to log on the front-end, JavaScriptSnippet is being used:

```
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet
```

...

```
@Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)
```

The problem is that everything in `pageViews` has a different `operation_Id` to everything in `requests`. So I don't know which pageView (and session ID) is associated with which request(s), dependencies, traces, etc.

Is there something additional that should have been done with the JavaScriptSnippet or some other configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can open an issue on GitHub: [ApplicationInsights-JS](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS)

Comment: You can refer to [Telemetry correlation in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation) and [Snippet based setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#snippet-based-setup)